# How to use \textbackslash

Tags: symbols

Been looking around and everywhere it tells me to use `\textbackslash` in LaTeX.

However if I write a text "yadayadayada in `\textbackslash` c `\textbackslash` f we have...."

A demonstration or so would be highly apprectiated. Thanks for helping a noob.

Comment: A demonstration of what? What are you trying to achieve? Please describe your problem.

Comment: Ah sorry.. what happens is that I get a warning and it doesn't work. I was thinking that I wanted a demonstration in the correct form to write something like "\hi" <- without the "" in LaTeX. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: If you are trying to write verbatim short text, you can use `\verb+\hi+`.

Comment: @Gonzalo: This should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to write verbatim short text, you can use `\verb+\hi+`; for longer verbatim texts you can use the `verbatim` environment; for further customizable possibilities you can use, for example, the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write

> \hi

in normal text (not verbatim) use `\textbackslash{}hi` or `\textbackslash hi`. (I'm not sure if there's any real difference between the two.)

Comment: use `\def\CS#1{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}` and `\CS{hi}`

Comment: @Herbert I don't quite understand what you're responding to. Your solution gives me a macro for outputting Typewriter style text preceeded by a backslash; I was, however, proposing a solution in normal font style since I didn't see Donut saying that they wanted Typewriter/verbatim style (nor that a macro was needed?).

Comment: @donherry: it is more or less common to set commands in typewriter font

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109968/my-mathcalu-turns-out-to-be-curvy-different-than-default#comment241396_109968 ... `:)`

Comment: I do not understand what you want to say?

Comment: @Herbert That wasn’t directed at you; I just wanted to point to the origin of the downvote to this answer since I consider it ... extraordinary.