# My \mathcal{U} turns out to be curvy? (different than default)

Tags: fonts, symbols, texshop

My preamble :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.81cm,tmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.52cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} % add to TOC
\usepackage{caption}
```

When I add the command :

```
 $\mathcal{U}$
```

I get

[image]

instead of

[image]

Can anyone tell me why is that happening ? and how to get the second `U` instead of my current one.

Comment: It's because you are loading `mathptmx`.

Comment: -1: What kept you from removing the packages e.g. one by one until you found the culprit?

Comment: @doncherry Because I'm a newbie and just started using Latex recently. My knowledge about how packages work and the possible relation to problems such as this is limited. I would never have thought that the packages are related.    Thanks for the -1, very supportive of you.

Comment: @NLed Not meaning to be a turn-off, but you seem to have understood the notion that a package adds some kind of functionality, and that it must be because of some package that you’re not getting the output you want. Finding out which package it is is just the logical next step, which I consider to be part of the “research effort” which is part of the basis for votes. In your defense, I’m surprised that in none of your 23 questions you’ve been pointed to our [minimal working example (MWE) thread](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It’s standard use to create and provide a MWE for tex.sx.

Comment: Oh and please don’t tell me you just revenge-downvoted me at [How to use \textbackslash](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15646)? How old are we?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because you are loading `mathptmx`, which also changes the math fonts. If you want to keep the `mathptmx` package, but with the original `\mathcal` symbols, use

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{U}$

\end{document}
```

If you are only interested in changing the text fonts, but keeping the math fonts, instead of `mathptmx` you could use `newtxtext` package instead:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{U}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great !! I keep discovering hidden tips about LaTeX almost daily !!

Answer (score 1):

To obtain an ordinary `\mathcal`, please comment the

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

line in your file.

BTW: do you really need all these packages?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yeah I know I have a lot of packages .. It's a dissertation so I try to make it look good :)